# SSRS Nested IIF in Switch Statement

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Wondering why IIF statement is not working inside Switch statement. Anyone can help me on this since I can't figure out the mistakes in the code. Or is it valid to put IIF inside Switch statement?

```
=Switch(
Ucase(Parameters!GroupBy.Value) = "ORGANIZATIONUNIT", 
         IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value 
                AND PREVIOUS(Fields!OrganizationUnitID.Value) = Fields!OrganizationUnitID.Value
                                , ""
                                ,Fields!LastName.Value),
Ucase(Parameters!GroupBy.Value) = "LEARNINGRESOURCE",
        IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value 
                AND PREVIOUS(Fields!LearningResourceID.Value) = Fields!LearningResourceID.Value
                                , ""
                                ,Fields!LastName.Value),
Ucase(Parameters!GroupBy.Value) = "SSRS.PROMPTS.LRCATEGORYID",
        IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value 
                AND PREVIOUS(Fields!LearningResourceCategoryID.Value) = Fields!LearningResourceCategoryID.Value
                                , ""
                                ,Fields!LastName.Value),
Ucase(Parameters!GroupBy.Value) = "REPORTINGCATEGORY",
        IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value 
                AND PREVIOUS(Fields!LearningResourceReportingCategoryID.Value) = Fields!LearningResourceReportingCategoryID.Value
                                , ""
                                ,Fields!LastName.Value),
Ucase(Parameters!GroupBy.Value) = "SUPERVISOR",IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value 
                AND PREVIOUS(Fields!SupervisorPersonID.Value) = Fields!SupervisorPersonID.Value
                                , ""
                                ,Fields!LastName.Value),
                TRUE
                , IIF(PREVIOUS(Fields!PersonID.Value) = Fields!PersonID.Value
                    , ""
                    ,Fields!LastName.Value)
)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me; can you elaborate on what the problem is? In what way is this not working?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?    What is it?